# Свайпер обрезает часть блока, которая должна остаться

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, слайдер, swiper

У swiper-container по умолчанию стоит `overflow: hidden;`. Из-за этого он обрезает часть слайдов по оси-Y. Если я поменяю на `overflow: visible;`, то по оси-Y будет всё ок, а вот по оси-X будет видна часть следующего блока.
Сам вопрос: Как сделать так, чтобы по оси-X след. блоки скрывались, а по оси-Y всё было как нужно?

https://roderen.github.io/bonsai/ (слайдер в самом низу)

P.S. Скрывать и показывать по этим двум осям я пробовал и ничего не выходит...

Answer (score 0):

к сожалению, когда мы применяем `overflow: hidden` это применяется к обоим осям, и нет возможности по одной скрывать, а по другой нет.

Как решение Вашей проблемы, можно добавить паддинги у блока с каруселью. Этот код решает Вашу проблему.

```
.swiper-container {
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 55px;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]